# MVC Viewbag Updated Value Not Showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a `ViewBag` in my page. When the page is loading, it is showing the `ViewBag` value.

I also have a `DropDownList`. I want to change the `ViewBag` value on selection change event and post the value to the `Controller` via `ajax`. `Controller` is also returning the proper value.

In my code the `ViewBag` is being updated, but it is not being displayed on the html(on browser).

I don't have any kind of clue why its not working!

My `View`

```
<div id="UserSelection">--Select User--
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item1, new SelectList(Users, "ID", "Names"), new { ID = "UserSelection", @Style = "width:50%;border:none" })
</div>

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.UserID)
```

My `Controller`

```
public ActionResult Permission()
{
    ViewBag.UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    ViewBag.Permissions = Session["PermissionCollection"] as List<int>;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Users(string UserID)
{
    List<int> data = new List<int>();
    int id = Convert.ToInt16(UserID);

    Permission perm = new Permission();
    data = perm.SlectedPermissions(id);

    ViewBag.UserID = UserID.ToString();
    ViewBag.Permissions = data as List<int>;

    return View("Permission");
}
```

My `jQuery`

```
$("#UserSelection").change(function () {
    var ID = $('#UserSelection option:selected').val();
    console.log(ID);
    $("#empID").val(ID);
    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Permission/Users")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { UserID: ID },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });               
});
```

Comment: How do you expect the data to be updated when you are making an ajax call and not updating the front end with your result?  I bet if you did a normal post it would work fine

Comment: Change `url: '@Url.Content("~/Permission/Users")',` to `url: '@Url.Action("Users", "Permission")',`. Content is used for static files (i.e. images) while Action is used for urls in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your view `Permissions.cshtml` does not using `ViewBag.Permissions`.

You can `access ViewBag data only in the returning view`, in this case it is Permissions.cshtml.

This `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.UserID)` code is defined in a main view and not part of Permissions view. Hence it is not working for you